# How do I put bytes object in a string? Python

Tags: python, sockets, encryption, rsa

1. I have an RSA encrypted message (bytes)
2. I want to make a string: `f'!e {encrypted_message}'`
3. Then I need to encode it so I can send it through socket

I try to decode my message so I can put it in a string, but instead I get this:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4`.

How do I put my message (bytes object) in a string?

Comment: You have to *decode* the bytes to a `str`... but why move to a string if you are just going to encode it? Why not `b'!e ' + message`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good question. My answer assumes their socket protocol is text-oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really do need a text (ASCII for the sake of this discussion) string with a `!e`  prefix for your wire protocol, the bullet-proof way to turn any bytes to text is Base64.

Happily, `base64.b64encode()` returns bytes, so you can use a bytestring and +.

```
import base64

my_bytes = b'asdf'
bytes_with_prefix_for_the_socket = b'!e ' + base64.b64encode(my_bytes)
```